# Issue link in allure jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, allure

How to configure ISSUE link for allure jenkins plugin?
There are only "Default Results Directories" and "Default Report Version" settings in global jenkins settings.
Allure report is generated normally after test, but Issue links are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That configuration has already been implemented (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jenkins-plugin/pull/39), but still not merged :( .

So, IMO you have only few options. Either build snapshot artifact with that patch applied or launch Jenkins with JVM arg -Dallure.issues.tracker.pattern=http://your-bug-tracker.com/%s (but you will have to ensure it exists for slave machines as well).

Comment: So I can just wait for Allure plugin v.2.3.3?

Comment: Yes, if that is acceptable to wait, that configuration earlier or later will be in future release.

Comment: I think we'll do a release when the latest PR get merged.

Comment: Allure plugin 2.5 is released, but there is still no such configuration in it.
Something changed?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed. https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jenkins-plugin/pull/39 is still open. I will ask the guys.

Comment: @sharadjain Yes, latest version (2.7) should have global Jenkins setting requested.

Comment: @Miheys Thanks I see it now.